# Help with reading xml

Tags: xml

I am struggling to extract data from an XML file. The file for all intense and purposes looks like this:

```
<Message>
  <Code>Hello </Code>
  <Code>bye </Code>
</Message>
```

At the moment I am using the Value function.

However the data I get returned is only ever "Hello". How do I return all data in a tabular format, like so:

[image]

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about MS-Sql you can use this syntax:

> ```
> DECLARE @data xml;
>
> SET @data = 
> '<Message>
>   <Code>Hello </Code>
>   <Code>bye </Code>
> </Message>';
>
> SELECT d.lin.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as [Code]
> FROM   @data.nodes('Message/Code') d(lin)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | Code   |
> | :----- |
> | Hello  |
> | bye    |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=42ca32484d49218f043c06202b4baa8a)*